# Unit disk as cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of real numbers. For each of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, determine whether it is equal to the cartesian product of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

**(a)** $\{(x,y):y>x\}$ and **(b)** $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2<1\}$

**Proof:** Consider an example (b). Let $C:=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2<1\}=A\times B$ where $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$. Since $\{0\}\times (-1,1)\subset C=A\times B$ then $(-1,1)\subset B$ and applying the same for $(-1,1)\times \{0\}$ we get that $(-1,1)\subset A$. Hence $(-1,1)\times (-1,1)\subset A\times B=C$. Taking the point $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\in (-1,1)\times(-1,1)\subset A\times B=C.$ Then by the definition of $C$ we get that $(\sqrt{3}/2)^2+(\sqrt{3}/2)^2=3/2<1$. This contradiction proves that unit circle cannot be equal to the cartesian product of some $A$ and $B$, where $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Is this proof correct?

If yes, would be grateful to see some alternative proof.

P.S. The same reasoning is applicable for (a).

Comment: Your proof is correct and more or less has the same idea as the standard proof.

Answer (score 2):

I think you overcomplicated the explanation of the proof a bit, but of course it is correct. 
You could have simply said $(0.99, 0), (0,0.99)\in C$, so if it were a direct product, $(0.99, 0.99)\in C$, but it isn't.